# Why can't I set the primary key in a django-dynamic-fixture fixture?

Tags: django

I have the following code:

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    sample_model_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    some_date = models.TextField()

def some_function():
    s = G(SampleModel, sample_model_id=1234, some_data='abcd')
    assert s.sample_model_id == 1
    assert s.some_data == 'abcd'
```

The assert statements pass (they are true statements).  Any idea why I can't set the sample_model_id?

I am using Python 2.7, Django 1.4.5, and django-dynamic-fixture 1.6.5 (the latest version).

Comment: What does `G` function (or class) do?

Comment: Good question, it is part of the django-dynamic-fixture library. It creates a Django model instance and fills in any unspecified values with sample values. For example, had I not specified some_data, it would have receive the sample value '1', or it would have been set to null if that was an option (eg, null=True was set in the model definition). I expect anyone able to answer the question would know what the function does.

Comment: I get an expected result when I use automatic `id`. Why do you use custom AutoField?

Comment: I am working with legacy code that has lots of custom AutoFields. I would be happy if the django-dynamic-fixture library supported custom primary key field names.

Comment: I found a workaround. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
class SampleModel(models.Model):
    some_data = models.TextField()
```

If I use above class (using automatic `id` field), I get expected result.

```
>>> from django_dynamic_fixture import G, get
>>> s = G(SampleModel, id=1234, some_data='abcd')
>>> s.id
1234
>>> s.some_data
'abcd'
```

With Sample model given in the question, get same result with the question.

Specifying `id` instead of `sample_model_id` raises an exception.

```
>>> s = G(SampleModel, id=1234, some_data='abcd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_dynamic_fixture/__init__.py", line 107, in get
    return d.get(model, shelve=shelve, **kwargs)
  File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_dynamic_fixture/ddf.py", line 507, in get
    instance = self.new(model_class, shelve=shelve, named_shelve=named_shelve, **kwargs)
  File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_dynamic_fixture/ddf.py", line 436, in new
    self.set_data_for_a_field(model_class, instance, field, persist_dependencies=persist_dependencies, **configuration)
  File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_dynamic_fixture/ddf.py", line 348, in set_data_for_a_field
    data = self._process_field_with_default_fixture(field, model_class, persist_dependencies)
  File "/home/falsetru/.virtualenvs/django15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_dynamic_fixture/ddf.py", line 335, in _process_field_with_default_fixture
    data = self.data_fixture.generate_data(field)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/code.py", line 216, in interact
    sys.ps2
UnsupportedFieldError: polls.models.SampleModel.sample_model_id
```

**UPDATE**

### Work around

Specify both `id` and `sample_model_id`.

```
>>> s = G(SampleModel, id=1234, sample_model_id=1234, some_data='abcd')
>>> s.sample_model_id
1234
>>> s.some_data
'abcd'
```

Actually, `id` value is not used internally; You can specify any value for `id`.

```
>>> s = G(SampleModel, id=None, sample_model_id=5555, some_data='abcd')
>>> s.sample_model_id
5555
>>> s.some_data
'abcd'
```